# Inject NVD3 custom tooltip into DOM with React

Tags: reactjs, nvd3.js

I am successfully using the `chart.interactiveLayer.tooltip.contentGenerator` hook to inject a stringed component (using `ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup`) as a custom tooltip in NVD3 1.8.6. in Chrome.

In NVD3's tooltip.js file on line 291 there is this comment:

`Bonus - If you override contentGenerator and return false, you can use something like Angular, React or Knockout to bind the data for your tooltip directly to the DOM.`

I'd like to know how to do this as I can't work out how this may be possible.  It would be a more performant solution and possibly resolve issues I'm having with IE11.

---

**Resolved.**  Here is a working solution in typescript (the current typing doesn't include the element argument):

```
chart.interactiveLayer.tooltip.contentGenerator(
        (d, element?: Element) => {
          if (element !== undefined) {
            ReactDOM.render(
              <Component data={d} />,
              element
            );
          }
          return '';
        }
      );
```